# Centos 6.6 Upgrade PHP to 5.4

Tags: apache, centos6

I'm trying to upgrade my php version (5.3.3) to a on a Centos 6.6 to get a 5.4's php's version (I'm a noob on server's configuration, in fact I'm a developer).

I've followed this tutorial http://sharadchhetri.com/2015/04/04/install-php-5-4-on-centos-6-with-yum-command/, I've followed what the first comment  said (because It add MySql support).

My problem is that when I make this command line "source /opt/rh/php54/enable", I've php 5.4 on a cli context but not when I asked for a php script with my browser (making a basicallly phpinfo();).

I'va tryied as they said "To make PHP 5.4 available to all user ..." but nothing change.

I'm looking everywhere and I can't find any solution. Anyone has an idea ?

Regards,
Zé.

Comment: Thanks for -2 without any explanations....It really helps...

Answer (score 1):

Notice: PHP 5.4 have reached its EOL (End of Life), so I highly recommend you upgrade to 5.5 or 5.6.

Tips: use the remi's repository configuration wizard: http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 0):

For the one who have the same problem, I've solve it by installing php 5.4 with remi's repository : https://www.zerostopbits.com/how-to-upg ... entos-6-7/

for information, I also had a problem with some package version, I have to change the remi's repository priority as explained https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManageme ... Priorities on "5. Specific Configuration"

Regards,
Ze.

Comment: Tips: use the remi's repository configuration wizard: http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/